# How to copy wildcard files to their relative directory under a new root?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, xcopy

I am looking to copy all files from directory a to directory b, keeping the structure of directories under a and creating any directories needed under b, but not erasing the contents of what is under b.

For example, say the folder structure looks like:

```
B
|--Foo.txt


A
|--Dir1
   |--Foo2.txt
```

After the copy it would be:

```
B
|--Foo.txt
|--Dir1
   |--Foo2.txt
```

Ideally I'd like to do this in batch calling xcopy or some other copy exe.  If not, I can probably code it myself in perl or C#, but if there is a nice way to use existing tools, could you let me know?  Thanks.

Comment: If there is a Foo.txt in directory A, what do you want to do in that case?

Comment: `xcopy /S /E /I "A\" "B\"` -- the `/E` switch lets `xcopy` copy also empty directories; add `/Y` to force overwriting without prompt in case a file already exists in the destination...

Answer (score 0):

xcopy will do the trick.  Tell it to copy subdirectories as well:

```
xcopy a\*.* b /shercky
```